# snap store vs ubuntu software

Tags: software-center, snap

I usually use `sudo apt install <program>` to install software but occasionally install via Ubuntu-software application if I want an app to appear in the Applications menu. From what I gather, the snap store is similiar but allows also to download/install from terminal, `snap install <program>`.

Is there a difference between the Snap Store and Ubuntu software?

Is there any reason to install via Snap rather than Ubuntu Software application?

Thanks

Comment: Ubuntu Software application is just like a front end for APT and Snap.

Comment: The path, by default, seems to be different for applications installed with it, than with apt. Are there any other differences?

Comment: Paths depends on the application. Snaps have different folders and packages from APT has different folders. But again Ubuntu Software doesn't decide which will go where. Scroll down to Application detail page and see if it's a snap or not and check it's folder.

Comment: Thanks for that, found the binary in `/snap/bin`.